# Espresso Test Failures with NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-espresso

Environment: Fedora 27, Android Studio 3.0.1, ConstraintLayout

I set up an Espresso test using an AVD in portrait node and the built in test recorder in Android Studio.  I ran the test on the AVD and it ran successfully.  I switched the AVD to landscape and the Espresso test failed.

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.xxx.xxx:id/myButton and Child at position 11 in parent Child at position 0 in parent with id: android:id/content and is displayed on the screen to the user)
```

I use a different layout for landscape, but the buttons are the same.  I am guessing the position numbers may not be the same as compared to the ones in the portrait layout.  I guess I could create a separate test for landscape, but I would rather use the same test for both.

I am wondering how can I see the position numbers of the objects in my layouts and can they ba changed so that an Espresso test can run on both orientations.mode

Update 1 - 19-JAN-2018
Recording Espresso test in Portrait

```
ViewInteraction appCompatImageButton13 = onView(
    allOf(withId(R.id.buttonClear),
        childAtPosition(
            childAtPosition(
                withId(android.R.id.content),
                0),
            11),
        isDisplayed()));
appCompatImageButton13.perform(click());
```

Test recorded in Landscape mode:

```
ViewInteraction appCompatImageButton13 = onView(
    allOf(withId(R.id.buttonClear),
        childAtPosition(
            childAtPosition(
                withId(android.R.id.content),
                0),
            25),
        isDisplayed()));
appCompatImageButton13.perform(click());
```

Comment: You use a lot of constraints to match the view, without the layout and the test is very difficult to guess.

Comment: Probably your view is visible in Portrait mode and is not visible on the screen in landscape. You should scroll down to make view visible then you can operate on it.

Comment: Can you not give each button a unique id or tag name? That way you will not need to use position numbers

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The buttons are all visible in both portrait and landscape layouts, although they are arranged differently to optimize each orientation. .  Each button in the portrait layout has a identical button in the landscape layout with a matching ID.  It is the position number that is different.  To clarify my question, how can I line up the position numbers so that one test will work for both portrait and landscape tests?  See update in the question for example button.